# Incircle of polygon tangent to a point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

How can we find the largest incircle (not sure if it is still called incircle) tangent to a given point on a side of a polygon? Instead of being tangent to all sides of the polygon, it will be tangent to at least two sides.

[image]

Since the centre of the target circle is on the blue line (perpendicular to the polygon's side at point $P$), we can test the possible circles to find the largest one.

However, this is a trial and error approach. I look for a mathematical solution.

Comment: Note that you will need at least three points to define a circle. The points can be on the sides (the circle is tangent), or, for concave polygons, it can be a vertex. But a good place to start is to look at angle bisectors. For convex polygons the center of the circle must be one of the intersections of these lines.

Comment: @Andrei you could have a point and the center - two points, which is the case here.

Comment: Have perpendicular at P and then use the closest intersection to P of the perpendicular with the bisectors. This will be the center of the desired circle.

Comment: @Moti. You are right. I did not see that the point P is given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express the line at $P$ perpendicular to its side as the curve $$\gamma : t \mapsto P +t\hat n$$
where $\hat n$ is the unit inward pointing normal vector to the side.

There are two ways the circle can be limited. As shown, it could be tangent to another side. But also, if that inward pointing vertex were lower, the increasing circle might run into the vertex before it became tangent to any side.
So calculate:

- For each vertex $V_i$, solve the equation $t^2 = d^2(V_i, \gamma(t))$ to find the $t$ for the circle tangent at $P$ and passing through $V_i$.
- For each side $\overline{V_iV_{i+1}}$, assume the point of tangency is at $Q_s = (1-s)V_i + sV_{i+1}$. Find the equation of the line perpendicular to the side and passing through $Q_s$. Intersect that line with $\gamma$, and label that point $C_s$. The equation $$d^2(C_s, P) = d^2(C_s, Q_s)$$ can be solved to find $s$. If $s < 0$ or $s > 1$, no circle tangent at $P$ will also be tangent to this side. In that case, discard this side and move on. Otherwise, $t = d(C_s, P)$ gives the center of this circle on $\gamma$.

Among all the values for vertices and non-discarded sides, the smallest $t$ will be the circle you want.